# How to specify an individual log format for Tomcat's console-log using java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

Tags: tomcat, logging

I've several webapps deployed on my Tomcat-installation and I'm using `swallowOutput="true"` in my `context.xml` in order to achieve different 'per-webapp'-log-outputs, not just one big `catalina.out` together for all webapps. That work's fine. Therefore, I'm using a `logging.properties`-file for each webapp.

The webapps are generating log output by using basic `System.out.println`.

Now, I would like to define a very simple log-format to be generated by Tomcat by specifying

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%5$s %n
```

However, the generated logs always show the full format which I do not need, whatever/however I specify the format-string above:

```
22-Jun-2019 16:08:15.310 INFO [http-nio-80-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke backend Sat Jun 22 16:08:15 CEST 2019: ... output of the servlet's System.out.println-calls ...
```

I would like to generate a small and clearly laid out log without the „StandardWrapperValve“ etc tokens in each line.

My global `logging.properties` file is this:

```ini
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.SimpleFormatter

java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%5$s %n

org.apache.juli.SimpleFormatter.format=%5$s %n

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE

# To see debug messages for HTTP/2 handling, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.coyote.http2.level = FINE

# To see debug messages for WebSocket handling, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.tomcat.websocket.level = FINE
```

And the per-webapp `logging.properties` file is this:

```ini
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = webappX.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%5$s %n
1catalina.java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%5$s %n
org.apache.juli.SimpleFormatter.format=%5$s %n
```

As you can see, I've already tried different lines to set the format-string to different class names, e.g.:

- `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format`
- `1catalina.java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format`
- `org.apache.juli.SimpleFormatter.format`

as I've found some information about this on other StackOverflow threads, but none of them shows any effect. The log output format stays the same, always in full format. The format-string does not show any impact.

Thanx for any ideas,
Tombo

Comment: Which version of apache Tomcat are you using and where do you place the per-webapp logging.properties file?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 8.5.15, the per-webapp logging.properties are situated at WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties. The per-webapp properties are showing an effect since the invidivual per-webapp console.logs are only created if the per-webapp logging.properties present. Without them everything goes to the general catalina.out.

Comment: And the custom format does not work with both: webbapp and tomcat general logging? Did you try a current version (e.g. 9.*)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested some variations on Tomcat 8.5.15 and found it seemes to be importent to also set the `org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter` in the per-webapp `logging.properties`.

So this is my full resulting per-webapp `logging.properties`:

```ini
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = webappX.
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

And in the global `apache-tomcat/conf/logging.properties` coming from the original, I only modified the `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter` and added the format:

```ini
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%5$s %n
```

The specified `SimpleFormatter.format` is effective for webApp log files if the webApp specifies `org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter` within the per-webapp `logging.properties`. It's also  effective for the raw console output.

Comment: Thank you for trying out correcting the conf-files. That looks straight-forward and does work fine, now! Howereve, System.out.println of the ServletContextListener.contextInitialized routine still goes to the global catalina.out. It seems as if the per-webapp properties get active afterwards. Any idea about that?

Comment: Maybe you have to add a consolhandler to the per per-webapp config. I removed that. Doesn't generally everything go to the catalina.out?